# What will happen if two process builders having same criteria but updating different values

Tags: process-builder, criteria

I have a Process Builder with a criteria which will update case owner as "Queue A" , another Process Builder with the same criteria that will update the case owner as "Queue B". Now, if the criteria is met, the new record will have which values in both of the above ?

When I tried this , I'm getting the second value being updated. Is this the intended one ?

Answer (score 0):

Like workflow rules, two different process builder flows that both trigger "when a record is created or updated" will have an undefined order. It may end up being the first value set or the second, depending on how the system chooses to execute the process builder flows. For this reason, we're allowed to create process builder flows that trigger from other process builder flows. By explicitly defining an order, they will fire in a deterministic order of your choosing.